# not able to access angular js page in web dynamic project

Tags: javascript, angular

every one i am very new to angular js so , i want to use **angular concepts like routing using ngRoute** in order to achieve my requirement .

here is my js code

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'StudentController' 
        })
        .when('/viewStudents', {
            templateUrl: 'viewStudents.html',
            controller: 'StudentController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
});

mainApp.controller('StudentController', function($scope) {
    $scope.students = [
        {name: 'Mark Waugh', city:'New York'},
        {name: 'Steve Jonathan', city:'London'},
        {name: 'John Marcus', city:'Paris'}
    ];

    $scope.message = "Click on the hyper link to view the students list.";
});
```

here is my index.html

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>AngularJS Routing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div ng-app="mainApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28//angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is home.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2> Welcome </h2>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <a href="#/viewStudents"> View Students List</a>
</div>
```

when i open index.html in browser it has to load home.html as mentioned in the js code.

but i am getting following error in the console

```
angular.js:8632 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///E:/battleField/angular/WebContent/WEB-INF/home.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

whats wrong with my code and way of running page . please help me to get out of this i referred following tutorial to get it 
**https://www.journaldev.com/6225/angularjs-routing-example-ngroute-routeprovider**

there its working fine.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is happening because you are just opening html documents directly from the browser. To fix this you will need to call your page from a webserver and access it on localhost. Use Wamp Server or Apache or if you have nodejs setup then use http-server

Comment: i am running it on tomcat server this is my path `http://localhost:8088/angular/WEB-INF/index.html` but i am getting 404 error

Comment: @bharathvarma but error is for file:///E:/battleField/angular/WebContent/WEB-INF/home.html your localhost setup is not working otherwise it would have given error at http://localhost:8088/angular/WEB-INF/home.html

Comment: yes sorry for misleading now i am not getting error in the console when running on localhost but i am not getting index page in browser its 404 error

Comment: i didn't find a route for index page

Comment: this error was due to web server problem..which is solved now...and if you see the question for which this is marked duplicate also stats the same answer as me..so can you just mark it correct? because it did solve your issue @bharathvarma

Comment: its working thank you.